# Find a bijective map $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R − \{0\}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I tried $f(x)=\frac1x$, but then domain is $\Bbb R-\{0\}$. When we divide functions into two parts, for example, when domain is $\{0\}$, $f(x)$ is something, but we have to consider that function must be bijective. What do you think?

Comment: $f(x) = x+1$ if $x$ is a non-negative integer, and $f(x)=x$ otherwise.

Comment: what about range (0,1) though, range must be R-{0}

Comment: $f(0.367)=0.367$ etc, all reals except $0$ are in the range

Comment: There is a simple way to find a bijection from an infinite $A$ to $A -\{x\}$.  Do you know it? The identity map is a bijection.  But it maps $0$ to $0$ and we don't have $0$ in the codomain... so we must map $0$ to somewhere else.  So map $0\mapsto 1$.  But now we must map $1$ to somewhere else.... So map it to $2$.  Now we must map $2$ to somewhere else.... so map it to $3$ and so on.  For every $n\in \mathbb N$ map it to $n+1$.  Everything else .... just map to itself.  That'll do $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&x=0\\ x+1&x\in\mathbb N\\ x&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Comment: If you think about this this is just the hilbert hotel.  The only difference is that all the people who are not in a natural numbered room are allowed to stay put.

Comment: "what about range (0,1) though, range must be R-{0}"  Not a problem.  If $x\in(0,1)$ then $f(x) = x$ and the function is still surjective.  And if $f(w) =x \in (0,1)$ then $x\not\in \mathbb N$ so $w\not \in \mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ so $x=f(w)=w$ so $x=w$ so the function is still injective.